# Jquery image preview ie6 and newer

Tags: jquery

I'm working with jquery 1.8.3 and I'm trying to make a cross-browser image preview.
This has to be supported on IE6 and up, Firefox and Chrome. Especially IE is important and that's where all my heartache begins.

The html I'm using is the following:

```
<div>
    <div id="preview">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="companypicture" id="companypicture" />
        <a href="" class="overviewdelete">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery I'm trying to get to work:

```
$('#companypicture').on('change', function () {

        var file = $('#companypicture').val();
        var image = $('<img>').attr('src', file);
        $('#preview').html(image);
    });
```

I have also tried:

```
$('#companypicture').on('change', function () {

        var file = $('#companypicture').val();
        var html = '<img src="' + file + '" alt="" />';
        $('#preview').html(html);
    });
```

All this does is give me a broken link. I get the alt text of the image, because the link isn't correct.

I have also tried the FileReader. FileReader works in IE10, but not on 6-7-8-9. Since it has to work from IE6 and up, there was no solution there.

As I've been trying to find answers on Google, I can't seem to find any there. I hope somebody here can help me.

EDIT: The current suggestion is that I upload the file to my server, then use the link from there to show the image and finally to delete the link again.

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for the tip. The problem still remains though, because live also works fine (for now).

Comment: To the person who downvoted: Mind giving me the reason why you downvoted? Feedback is always appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand how can you get and use file source of an image, which has been uploaded recently... Try to avoid using `var file`, `var html` and so on, it causes problems sometimes. Can you add jsfiddle example?

Comment: As you requested, here is teh JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teKEG/5/ I have updated it so I don't use var file and the likes of it.
What I'm trying to do is get the preview of the image before it is uploaded. So it's still on the local computer of the user and not on the server.

Comment: You cannot get the full local path of a file upload in any browser. It is a security feature built into the browser.

Comment: Do you happen to know an alternative for what I'm trying to do then? FielReader is not an option because that's only from IE10. The solutions I posted above are ones that I've found via Google. IE9 returns the full path, but <img src="path" /> doesn't accept it. So none of them work anymore.

Comment: You can save that image temporary somewhere and delete after user clicks save. Use jQuery `ajax()` to save image and after you will easily get image path :)

Comment: You can add that as an answer. If nobody comes up with a different way to do it, then I'll mark it as answer. It's kind of a shame that I can't use FileReader, because it worked perfectly in IE10.

Comment: I don't care about reputation points :) Let's leave as it is :)

Comment: @Morpheus - It's not just about points. Answers help people find resolutions to these problems further down the line. Points are secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the full local path of a file upload in any browser. It is a security feature built into the browser. You can save that image temporary somewhere and delete after user clicks save. Use jQuery ajax() to save image and after you will easily get image path :)